# Using / Implementation of Web Sockets Server side

Tags: html, websocket, npm

I am new to Web Sockets and I want to know how the web sockets is being implemented at the server side?.. for client side I can write onmessage() etc in html5...JavaScript etc... But for server side I have so many options. I am confused how to implement it in server side and how can I write a server side code either in JavaScript or C through node.js or npm or web sockets.io?? how can i install them or is there any sdk ..what is the installation procedure ?

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the server-side options you mention in your question are related to the same technology, namely node.js.

1. [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is a server-side JavaScript solution based on Google's v8 engine designed for building scalable web-applications
2. [npm](http://npmjs.org/) is a package manager for node which allows you to install and publish node programs and manage their dependencies. It's similar in some ways to the package managers available on some linux distributions (rpm and apt for example).
3. [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is a plug-in for node.js for developing real time applications. It selects the [most suitable transport mechanism](http://socket.io/#browser-support) for the client but hides the details behind a single API.

If you're building a real-time application I can definitely recommend looking in more detail at node and socket.io.

The [node download page](http://nodejs.org/#download) has installers for Windows and Mac, and there are various guides to [installing node on Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=Google%20Search&q=ubuntu%20install%20node).

Comment: so it means that for server side coding of the web sockets I need to have node.js etc mentioned above. And Node can be installed on Windows as well right??

Comment: Uh ? There are websocket implementations in all major languages, no need to use node.js if it's not wanted. The pros and cons of node.js should at least be studied before choosing it for a real project.

Comment: Sorry, dystroy is COMPLETELY correct; I misread the comment as "to use socket.io I need to have node.js installed". You can indeed implement websockets in all major server-side languages and you should consider the pros and cons of each before selecting one. I think you'll find the pros of node.js quite compelling however. :)